# Why is using `which` faster when subsetting a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

According to the following benchmarks, `which` is approx 5% faster than not using `which`. Does anyone know why?

```
> microbenchmark(mtcars[mtcars$gear == 4 | mtcars$gear == 3,], times = 100000)
Unit: microseconds
                                          expr     min      lq     mean  median      uq      max neval
 mtcars[mtcars$gear == 4 | mtcars$gear == 3, ] 179.104 190.334 212.0044 194.876 199.662 85451.69 1e+05



> microbenchmark(mtcars[which(mtcars$gear == 4 | mtcars$gear == 3),],  times = 100000)
Unit: microseconds
                                                 expr     min      lq     mean  median      uq      max neval
 mtcars[which(mtcars$gear == 4 | mtcars$gear == 3), ] 168.744 179.569 196.0215 184.326 188.981 75434.62 1e+05
```

Comment: Its impossible to say without profiling; take a look at rprof.  Have you tried the case of !=4?  If so, is that faster or not?